# Socket Program Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am making a hangman game. I am trying to send to the server that if lose == 7, then loseGame = true. And in the client Side, if loseGame is true, to print out that the game has been lost. I matched the send and recv, but it is not working and keeps on asking for input for guess the letter. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

I put THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS where I believe the problem is.

Thank you!

Server:

```
import sys

# Import socket library
from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 2:
    serverPort = 5895
# Get port number from command line
else:
    serverPort = int(sys.argv[1])

# Choose SOCK_STREAM, which is TCP
# This is a welcome socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Start listening on specified port
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))

# Listener begins listening
serverSocket.listen(1)

print("The server is ready to receive")

#Set secret word
word = 'arkansas'
linesForString = ''     
#Prints out number of letters
for x in word:
    linesForString += '_'

newWord = 'arkansas'

# Wait for connection and create a new socket
# It blocks here waiting for connection
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
win = ' '
#Sends lines of words
linesInBytes = linesForString.encode('utf-8')
connectionSocket.send(linesInBytes)

lose = 0
while 1:


    l = list(word)
    list2 = list(linesForString)

    win = False 

    while 1:

        while win == False:
            losee = 0
            # Receives Letter
            letter = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            letterString = letter.decode('utf-8')

            for x in range(len(list2)): 
                if(list2[x] == '_'):
                    if(letterString == l[x]):
                        list2[x] = letterString     

            for x in range(len(word)):
                if(letterString == word[x]):
                    losee = -1
            if (losee != -1):
                lose += 1

            print(lose)
            newWord = "".join(list2)

            #Sends newWord
            newWordInBytes = newWord.encode('utf-8')
            connectionSocket.send(newWordInBytes, lose)


            if(newWord == 'arkansas'):
                win = True
                winGame = 'You have won the game'
                winGameInBytes = winGame.encode('utf-8')
                connectionSocket.send(winGameInBytes)
                connectionSocket.close()


            if(lose == 7):
                loseGame = 'true'
                connectionSocket.close()
            else: 
                loseGame = 'false'

            #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
            loseGameInBytes = loseGame.encode('utf-8')
            connectionSocket.send(loseGameInBytes)  

# Close connection to client but do not close welcome socket
connectionSocket.close()
```

Client:

```
import sys

# Import socket library
from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 3:
    serverName = 'localhost'
    serverPort = 5895
# Get from command line
else:
    serverName = sys.argv[1]
    serverPort = int(sys.argv[2])

# Choose SOCK_STREAM, which is TCP
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to server using hostname/IP and port
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

#Recieves lines of words
linesInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
lines = linesInBytes.decode('utf-8') 
for x in lines:
    print(x, end = " ")

while 1:

    # Get letter from user
    print('\n')
    letter = input('Guess a letter: ')

    # Sends letter
    letterBytes = letter.encode('utf-8')
    clientSocket.send(letterBytes)

    #Recieves newWord
    newWordInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    newWord = newWordInBytes.decode('utf-8')

    for x in newWord:
        print(x, end = " ")
    print(" ")  

    if(newWord == 'arkansas'):
        winGameInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
        winGame = winGameInBytes.decode('utf-8')
        print(winGame)
        clientSocket.close()
        break

    #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS   
    loseGame = " "
    loseGameInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)   
    loseGame = loseGame.encode('utf-8')

    if(loseGame == "true"):
        print('You have lost the game!')
        clientSocket.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I had issues with until I could get it working:
1. notice when you take input use raw_input, otherwise it crashed for me.
2.where you thought there was an issue in the server there really was one. You accidentally close connection and then send once the game is lost
3. in the client you have `loseGame = loseGame.encode('utf-8')` instead of `loseGame = loseGameInBytes.encode('utf-8')`
4. I change the print statements to `print(str(x) + " "),` because yours gave me issues

This is the code after I fixed it. Notice I changed and added breaks in the server that aren't necessary and they will cause the server to close at the end of a single game.

server code:

```
import sys

# Import socket library
from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 2:
    serverPort = 5895
# Get port number from command line
else:
    serverPort = int(sys.argv[1])

# Choose SOCK_STREAM, which is TCP
# This is a welcome socket
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Start listening on specified port
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))

# Listener begins listening
serverSocket.listen(1)

print("The server is ready to receive")

#Set secret word
word = 'respecttheplatypus'
linesForString = ''     
#Prints out number of letters
for x in word:
    linesForString += '_'

newWord = 'respecttheplatypus'

# Wait for connection and create a new socket
# It blocks here waiting for connection
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
win = ' '
#Sends lines of words
linesInBytes = linesForString.encode('utf-8')
connectionSocket.send(linesInBytes)

lose = 0
while 1:


    l = list(word)
    list2 = list(linesForString)

    win = False 

    while 1:

        while win == False:
            losee = 0
            # Receives Letter
            letter = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            letterString = letter.decode('utf-8')

            for x in range(len(list2)): 
                if(list2[x] == '_'):
                    if(letterString == l[x]):
                        list2[x] = letterString     

            for x in range(len(word)):
                if(letterString == word[x]):
                    losee = -1
            if (losee != -1):
                lose += 1

            print(lose)
            newWord = "".join(list2)

            #Sends newWord
            newWordInBytes = newWord.encode('utf-8')
            connectionSocket.send(newWordInBytes, lose)


            if(newWord == 'respecttheplatypus'):
                win = True
                winGame = 'You have won the game'
                winGameInBytes = winGame.encode('utf-8')
                connectionSocket.send(winGameInBytes)
                connectionSocket.close()
            else:

                if(lose == 7):
                    loseGame = 'true'
                    loseGameInBytes = loseGame.encode('utf-8')
                    print(loseGame)
                    connectionSocket.send(loseGameInBytes)
                    connectionSocket.close()
                    break
                else: 
                    loseGame = 'false'
                #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
                    loseGameInBytes = loseGame.encode('utf-8')
                    print(loseGame)
                    connectionSocket.send(loseGameInBytes)  
        break
    break
```

client code:

```
import sys

# Import socket library
from socket import *

if sys.argv.__len__() != 3:
    serverName = 'localhost'
    serverPort = 5895
# Get from command line
else:
    serverName = sys.argv[1]
    serverPort = int(sys.argv[2])

# Choose SOCK_STREAM, which is TCP
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to server using hostname/IP and port
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

#Recieves lines of words
linesInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
lines = linesInBytes.decode('utf-8') 
for x in lines:
    print(str(x) + " "),

while 1:

    # Get letter from user
    print('\n')
    letter = raw_input('Guess a letter: ')

    # Sends letter
    letterBytes = letter.encode('utf-8')
    clientSocket.send(letterBytes)

    #Recieves newWord
    newWordInBytes = clientSocket.recv(len(linesInBytes))
    newWord = newWordInBytes.decode('utf-8')

    for x in newWord:
        print(str(x) + " "),
    print(" ")  

    if(newWord == 'respecttheplatypus'):
        winGameInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)
        winGame = winGameInBytes.decode('utf-8')
        print(winGame)
        clientSocket.close()
        break

    #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS   
    loseGame = " "
    loseGameInBytes = clientSocket.recv(1024)   
    loseGame = loseGameInBytes.encode('utf-8')

    print("lose game is" + str(loseGame))
    if(loseGame == "true"):
        print('You have lost the game!')
        clientSocket.close()
```